# Can't add icon to Action Right Click Drop Down Menu in Notes Client View

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, notesview

I am trying to add an icon to the Right Click, Drop Down Menu , on an Action, in a View.  The icon shows up in the Action Bar (with no text, but that is how it's supposed to work) at the top (see image) but in the drop down menu, it does not appear, only the text does.  Is there something I am missing?  Is this not suppported?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Carlo, have you resolved this issue? Because I have the same problem, i have config a icon to the right button action but I cant see the icon, like you.

Comment: no, was never able to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this feature is only supported for actions in the action bar:

[image]

Comment: Georg, I'm getting that same impression.  Based on the icons that are displayed in the right click menu for shared actions (see 2nd image), I was hoping there was an undocumented method, but none that I can find.